# Populate a column of DataGridView with same Value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, populate

I have a Winforms DataGridView with say 3 columns,and the last column is Called as 'Add'. Now I have to populate that column with a text 'Add' in all the rows likes shown above.
[image: Column]

Now to populate every row with the same text, I only know by using a for-loop on the entire gridview's row collection and assigning the text. So I wanted to know if there is any other way too, through which this can be achieved also, which doesn't involve any for-loops.
Thanks !

Comment: winforms? wpf? asp.net ?

Comment: I'm so sorry , forgot to mention. It is for Winforms.

Comment: Add a TextBoxColumn and add text as Add

Comment: @Krishna I just tried adding a  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn but I cannot see a Text property for the column. It would be helpful if you can share a sample code snippet.

Comment: My mistake, is this add a button ? or what the add represent ? Is this grid databound ?

Comment: @Krishna it is just a plain text which I want to show in every row of that column.

Comment: is it databound ? if so you can add column to datasource before binding right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set default value to the column as below
Add a textboxcolumn and set value like below

```
dataGridView1.Columns["columnName"].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Add";
```

if the grid is databound try to add this in the datasource which is easier.

Comment: Wow !! It worked. I was looking for something just like this !! Thank you!

Comment: Plus I didn't have to add any new  TextBoxColumn.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
var rows = myDataGridView.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select( c =>
{
    c.Cells[2].Value = "Add";//3rd column
    return c;
} ).ToArray();

myDataGridView.Rows.Clear();//Clear the rows so you can re-add them with the value
myDataGridView.Rows.AddRange( rows );
```

`Cells[2]` means column with index 2, so in this example I will fill the 3rd column (of already filled rows) with the word `Add`.